# React Native DatePicker with TextInput

Tags: react-native, datepicker, textinput

I am currently making a mobile app and part of it is collecting user data. At the minute I am stuck on getting the DatePicker to show on screen once the text field has been clicked on. I have tried to use the onFocus prop but it does not seem to be working and its not throwing any errors in the console. Here is the code that i have tried using:

```
 const showDatePicker = () => {
       return(
           <DateTimePicker
               value={date}
               mode='date'
               is24Hour={true}
               display="spinner"
               onChange={onChange}
           />
       )
   }
```

```
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                                <FontAwesome name="user-circle-o" color={'#808080'} size={20}/>
                                <TextInput onFocus={() => showDatePicker()} style={styles.input} placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                                />
                            </View>
```

To give some additional context to the problem I am using a modal which acts as a form for collecting the data. Any help or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `TextInput` with a `<Pressable />`.

```
<Pressable onPress={() => showDatePicker()}>
    <TextInput />
</Pressable>
```

Comment: This is worked after I set `editable={false}` in TextInput props.